# How can I convert a pandas column of time to different columns of hours and minutes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a xlsx data that I imported and I have to work with int variables so i had to convert the datetimes columns to different columns(hour,minute, day...)
but I encountered a problem in my code and I don't know how to solve it
I already tried this:

```
DF_modified['hours'] = [int(x[:-3]) for x in DF_modified['time']]

List = np.array([x.split('.') for x in DF_modified['time']])

DF_modified['day'] , DF_modified['mounth'] , DF_modified['year'] = List[:,0], List[:,1], List[:,2]
DF['hours_dawn']=[int(x[:-3]) for x in DF['dawn']]
DF['minutes_dawn']=[int(x[3:]) for x in DF['dawn']]
DF['hours_dawn']=[x.hour for x in DF['dawn']]
DF['minutes_dawn']=[x.minute for x in DF['dawn']]
```

But I encounter an error in the first line:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.time' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `DF_modified.head()` and `DF.head()`

Comment: I think your approach is a bit to complicated. Have you tried `DF_modified['day'] = DF_modified['time'].dt.day`? check out the documents for more detailed infos: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {"time": ["2021/07/07:00:12:13", "2021/07/07:00:12:13"]
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S')
print(data)
data['Year'], data['Month'], data['day']  =data['time'].dt.year, 
data['time'].dt.month, data['time'].dt.day
data['hours'], data['min'], data['sec']  =data['time'].dt.hour, 
data['time'].dt.minute, data['time'].dt.second
print(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that (if `DF_modified['time'].dtype` is `datetime64`)

```
DF_modified['hours'] = DF_modified['time'].dt.hour
```